# Incorrect Syntax in Trigger creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger on one of my table in DB as below

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_JTIA_ForInsert
ON MyTable
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JTIItemID INT,
            @UserWWID INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM [MyTable] JTIA 
               INNER JOIN inserted NewItem ON NewItem.ItemID = JTIA.ItemID 
                                           AND NewItem.UserWWID = JTIA.UserWWID 
                                           AND NewItem.Status = JTIA.Status)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @JTIItemID = inserted.ItemID, 
            @UserWWID = inserted.UserWWID 
        FROM
            inserted

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @recipients = 'edwin@gmail.com', 
              @profile_name = 'App Administrator',
              @body = SELECT CONCAT('User : ',(SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),12345)), ' was assigned a duplicate JTIItemID: ', (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),1234567)), ' at timestamp: ', (select convert(varchar, getdate(), 22))),
              @subject = 'Duplicate record Was Assigned to user:'; 
    END
END
```

When I execute the above trigger I get the belwo error message on creation.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tr_JTIA_ForInsert, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tr_JTIA_ForInsert, Line 17 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@subject".

Not sure what am I missing

Comment: You need to build the `@body` of your e-mail message **before** the call to `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`. In the call to this system stored procedure, you should only use string literals and string variables - not have complicated `SELECT` and other logic to create the resulting stirng

Comment: Also: your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough reworked example of what you need. I don't have the table so I can't test it but I suspect it's pretty close.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_JTIA_ForInsert
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @JTIItemID int;
    DECLARE @UserWWID int;
    DECLARE @EmailBody nvarchar(max);

    DECLARE @EmailsToSend TABLE
    (
        EmailsToSendID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        JTIItemID int,
        UserWWID int
    );

    INSERT @EmailsToSend (JTIItemID, UserWWID)
    SELECT i.JTIItemID, i.UserWWID
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.MyTable AS mt
    ON mt.ItemID = i.ItemID 
    AND mt.UserWWID = i.UserWWID
    AND mt.[Status] = i.[Status];

    DECLARE @Counter int = 1;
    WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT MAX(EmailsToSendID) FROM @EmailsToSend)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @JTIItemID = ets.JTIItemID,
               @UserWWID = ets.UserWWID
        FROM @EmailsToSend AS ets
        WHERE ets.EmailsToSendID = @Counter;

        SET @EmailBody = CONCAT(N'User : ',
                                (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),12345)), 
                                N' was assigned a duplicate JTIItemID: ', 
                                (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),1234567)), 
                                N' at timestamp: ', 
                                (SELECT convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 22)));

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @recipients = N'edwin@gmail.com', 
              @profile_name = N'App Administrator',
              @body = @EmailBody,
              @subject = N'Duplicate record Was Assigned to user:'; 
        SET @Counter += 1;
    END;
END;
GO
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Just use a cursor - a while loop is no better and there is no advantage to applying the typically pointless pattern of dumping a bunch of rows into a temp table/table variable and then selecting from it